# Copy Dialog Box is not shown while copying

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer, copy-paste

I seem to have a peculiar problem in Windows. So let's get straight to the point, A few days back i've attempted to copy a 10GB folder between my desktop and an external hard drive.

When I copied the source folder and pasted it onto the destination, I felt something was fishy as the **copying dialog box displaying the progress of the transfer was absent**. I fired up the task manager and noticed **high disk activity(maxed out)**. After waiting for a while, I browsed to the destination location and found that the folder to be copied on to the external hard drive was actually there as it should, indicating the folder has been **copied successfully**.

This problem lingered ever since.
The copying operation is done without any mishaps **but without the progress bar**. I haven't tried any steps for troubleshooting this apart from a couple of reboots and a system restore

So what might be the problem assuming that I haven't tweaked the system in any way which can conflict with the operation?. Note: This happens for any copying operations in my system. I just don't see them anymore. 
Awaiting your responses.

[image: Here is a screenshot of disk activity indicating that the file is actually being copied].